# Can I change the components in my question from BJTs to FETs?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[Minimum components for BJT H-Bridge applied to a small 3-6V motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389075/minimum-components-for-bjt-h-bridge-applied-to-a-small-3-6v-motor-controlled-by?noredirect=1#comment949906_389075)

I acquiesce from the comments said from @ChrisStratton's (last one on the question), and by the discussion under @HenryCrun's answer.

I figure I can change the question from reading this: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.

---

So I want to change it to FETs, but still keep something about BJTs in the question...

Comment: Is the system preventing you from editing the question?

Comment: No. I made the edits.

Answer (score 5):

That question has answers which are in the context of BJTs.  If you change the existing question from BJTs to FETs, then the existing questions would loose context.  That wouldn't be good.

Here's what you could do, though.  Keep the existing text about BJTs as-is.  Edit the questions, add an update about your proposed FET approach.  The update can be as detailed as the initial question, or more so.  It can be as detailed as you need it to be.

Comment: Well, there's only one answer (besides mine). And he said to, "use the inverse circuit" for MOSFETs in a comment. So that's the proposed FET approach.